# How to schedule a task for X days from now?

Tags: org-mode

I oftentimes need to schedule items for 60 days from now or 90 days from now. Is there an easy way to schedule items for X days from today in org-mode?

Note that in Emacs's calendar, you can simply type `90 C-f` to go to 90 days from the date that point is at. This is basically what I'm looking for, but doesn't seem to work in the scheduler you get when you `C-c C-s` a header in org-mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The doc-string for `org-schedule` states that it accepts "a delta like `+2d`".  To read more about this function, type `M-x describe-function RET org-schedule RET`.  Try evaluating `(org-schedule nil "+90d")` -- i.e., `M-x eval-expression RET (org-schedule nil "+90d") RET`.  You can also call this function interactively, `M-x org-schedule RET +90d RET`.  The function `org-schedule` is bound by default to `C-c C-s`.